# Single application for touch and non-touch blackberry devices?

Tags: blackberry, operating-system, target, smartphone, mobile-application

Do i have to write different applications for **Blackberry touch devices** and **Blackberry non-touch devices**? or single application works for both?

Any suggestions for writing code for device using trackball or touch or both?
Suggest some references for the same.

Very much confused regarding

1. Which OS is to be targeted.
2. What devices should we acquire from client for testing the application?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming we're talking about Java apps here. If so, the same application will work on both touchscreen and non-touchscreen devices. You can use the [Touchscreen.isSupported()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Touchscreen.html#isSupported%28%29) API to determine what kind of device you're on.

Comment: is there anything else other than java apps for blackberry?